# Application asks to allow incoming communications but is already allowed in firewall preferences

Tags: macos, font, firewall

One of my login items is called FontAgent Activator.app

Each time I restart, I am prompted to accept incoming network communications for this app. However the app is already listed as allow incoming communications in the firewall preferences. This is the only app that has this issue.

Font Agent Pro support has not come up with a resolution. They said it might be a corrupt firewall. I deleted the firewall plist file completely and restarted, effectively resetting all the firewall preferences. I then have added apps to the list as needed, and that has not fixed it.

This dialog is getting annoying. Anyone know of a possible fix?

Thanks

example screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Is it properly signed ?

Comment: I would assume so, as it was installed by their installer. How would I be able to tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details, it is difficult to guess what might be causing this.

The first step I would take in troubleshooting this is to create a new user account; log into that account and install the application; and see if the behavior is the same via the new account - if it is, then the problem lies in the application itself; if not, then the problem lies in your user account.

Comment: In the install I installed font agent for all users on this computer. Would that effect this do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Agree on without more details one can not give more accurate answer.

I would say to check the FontAgent Activator.app for valid CA.

That might be the reason it wont pass the firewall automatically.

The trusted certificates are stored in your keychain.

Unfortunately I do not have the FontAgent to validate my answer.

The instruction says:
*This setting allows apps and services that are signed by a valid certificate authority to be automatically added to the list of allowed apps, rather than requiring you to authorize them. For example, iTunes is signed by Apple, and so it is automatically allowed to receive incoming connections through the firewall.*

When you installing software you are been asked if you trust them to proceed, and if you say yes they certificate is stored in your keychain. In keychain you cam modify the Trust level.

Comment: I looked in the keychain and didn't see any certificates for the fontagentproactivator app. Does that mean it does not use code signing?